# Groovy syntax issue for jenkins-pipeline with bash and groovy variable

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

getting issue for below stage. seems shell and groovy variable creating issue for execution.

```
  stage('Counting Codes') {


        steps {


            sh """


               groupName=$(curl -X GET "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/${GITLAB_GROUP}?private_token=$GITLAB_TOKEN}" | jq '.path' --raw-output)


               cat $groupName.lang
                
            """
        }
    }
```

Comment: + groupName=
+ cat .lang
cat: .lang: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You can escape all the non-groovy variables using a backslash.

```
sh """
  groupName=\$(curl -X GET "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/${GITLAB_GROUP}?private_token=$GITLAB_TOKEN}" | jq '.path' --raw-output)
  cat \$groupName.lang               
"""
```

Comment: its not working.







       + groupName=
       + cat .lang
        cat: .lang: No such file or directory

Comment: @GiridharKumarJha your groupName was not populated. You need to debug and see what's going on.